# Work around for multiple with definition

Tags: sql, teradata

My query consists of multiple `volatile tables` . In the final `select` statement i am using all those temporary volatile tables.

I need to transform the query into one huge `select` statement . i could have done this using `with` , however the server does not support multiple `with` definitions .

Is there any other way i could make the transformation ?

Comment: Can you post the SQL and Volatile Table definitions that you do have?

Comment: Multiple WITH are supported in TD14. Before you might simply use Derived Tables instead.

Comment: I use TD 13. Simple Derived tables could be used however this overcomplicated debugging . . i was hoping that TD 13 had something to substitute WITH